# C# Control Microphone volume form application

Tags: c#, .net, microphone, voice-recognition

want to control microphone volume from inside of my application, i tried to search it and tried many different solutions but haven't got any success :( all solutions are bit confusing and incomplete.

already spend lots of time so i need your help guys, if anybody help me to do this. i want to control Microphone level using c# from my application.

```
        get MicrophoneLevel
        set MicrophoneLevel
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope you just need to adjust the volume level for your own application only. You can do that with [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/) perhaps.

```
UnsignedMixerControl volumeControl;
int waveInDeviceNumber = 0;
var mixerLine = new MixerLine((IntPtr)waveInDeviceNumber, 
                               0, MixerFlags.WaveIn);

foreach (var control in mixerLine.Controls)
{
    if (control.ControlType == MixerControlType.Volume)
    {
        volumeControl = control as UnsignedMixerControl;        
        break;
    }
}

volumeControl.Percent = 30; // you are setting volume here, as a percentage.
```

For more information, refer to the article [.NET Voice Recorder](http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/NET-Voice-Recorder).